# Salesforce Remote Access permissions

Tags: security, salesforce, user-permissions

When you programmatically access Salesforce through Remote Access, what account permissions does the code have?

The `Consumer Key` for the remote access is created by a particular user, so does the Remote Access tool have the same permissions as that user?

Answer (score 2):

The user still has to authenticate via remote access, the resulting access token has the rights of the user that authenticated.

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I'm looking for. Do you have a reference documenting this?

Comment: login to salesforce pick help & training, search for remote access.